# Can't find out where my Angular minify bug is, do config or run functions require [] syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to go line by line to figure out where the problem is, does anything here need to change?

> Failed to instantiate module tickertags due to:
>     Error: [$injector:strictdi]   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/strictdi?p0=f...)
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://localhost/static/dashboard/libs/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
>       at Function.db.$$annotate

```
.constant('AUTH_EVENTS', {
    loginSuccess     : 'auth-login-success',
    loginFailed      : 'auth-login-failed',
    logoutSuccess    : 'auth-logout-success',
    sessionTimeout   : 'auth-session-timeout',
    notAuthenticated : 'auth-not-authenticated',
    notAuthorized    : 'auth-not-authorized'
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            data: {
                authorizedRoles: ['All']
            }
        });
})

.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push([
    '$injector',
    function ($injector) {
        return $injector.get('AuthInterceptor');
    }]);
})

.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, AUTH_EVENTS, $location) {
    return {
        responseError: function (response) { 
            $rootScope.$broadcast({
                401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
                403: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized,
                419: AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout,
                440: AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout
            }[response.status], response);
                if (response.status == 401) {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
})
```

My .run function

```
.run(function ($rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {

        var authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles;

        if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // user is not allowed
            if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
                $location.path('/login');

            // user is not logged in
            }
            else {
                $rootScope.ifLoggedOut = true;

                AuthService.check_login().then(function (user) {

                    $rootScope.ifLoggedOut = false;

                    if (user.role === 'Curator') {
                        $rootScope.isCurator = true;
                    }

                    $rootScope.currentUser = user;
                    $rootScope.username    = user.username;

                }, function() {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated);
                    $location.path('/login');
                });
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do need injectors to allow for minification.

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            data: {
                authorizedRoles: ['All']
            }
        });
}])

.config(['$httpProvider',
function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push([
    '$injector',
    function ($injector) {
        return $injector.get('AuthInterceptor');
    }]);
}])

.factory('AuthInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', 'AUTH_EVENTS', '$location',
function ($rootScope, $q, AUTH_EVENTS, $location) {
    return {
        responseError: function (response) { 
            $rootScope.$broadcast({
                401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
                403: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized,
                419: AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout,
                440: AUTH_EVENTS.sessionTimeout
            }[response.status], response);
                if (response.status == 401) {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
}])
```

Hopefully I didn't typo that, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks! How about something like a `Constant`? I just added it to my post. Adding a `run` function too

Comment: @LeonGaban The constant should be fine, but the run method will need the same kind of injection setup.

Comment: Thanks, looks like my problem is somewhere else in the code, but the above works non minimized...